# Are questions about MediaWiki syntax considered relevant on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ is intended for "users of web applications", while stackoverflow.com is intended for "professional and enthusiast programmers." If I want to post a question about MediaWiki syntax (i. e., the syntax for creating templates), would it be better to post the question on http://stackoverflow.com or on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/?

The question can be found here: [Highlight the text before a Wikipedia template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617772/highlight-the-text-before-a-wikipedia-template)

Comment: It's not easy to decide which of the two sites would be a better fit for this question - is wiki markup considered relevant on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Looks like only 4 of 63 are closed on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki

Comment: @random The vast majority of these questions aren't about wiki markup, though. Would questions about wiki markup be considered relevant on either Stack Overflow or webapps.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Include your sample question in the body

Comment: @random The question is located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617772/highlight-the-text-before-a-wikipedia-template

Comment: With [over 9K](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5BMediaWiki%5D) search results "MediaWiki" is *relevant* on a few different sites; the question is on-topic, though probably a duplicate.